# How do I sort a complex dictionary by a key, which resides deep the dictionary?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary with this structure:

```
{
  "Mark":
  {
    "surname":"Johnson",
    "tags":
    [
      {
        "name":"Salary",
        "value":"5"
      },
      {
        "name":"Car manufacturer",
        "value":"Volvo"
      }
    ]
  },
  "John":
  {
    "surname":"Doe",
    "tags":
    [
      {
        "name":"Salary",
        "value":"10"
      },
      {
        "name":"Car manufacturer",
        "value":"Daewoo"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to sort that dictionary by value of tag with a name 'Car manufacturer' to get something like this:

```
{
  "Volvo": 
  {
    [
     "Mark":{...},...
    ]
  },
  "Daewoo":
  {
    ["John":{...}]
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make it as elegant as possible? I can do it by making a couple of nested cycles (example below), but it looks ugly and probably not that efficient.

```
cars = {}
for person in persons:
  for tag in person['tags']:
    if tag['name'] == 'Car manufacturer'
      cars[tag['value']].append(item)
```

Comment: That's about as good as you'll get it; it's awkward because the starting data structure isn't very good.

Comment: You do not want a _sort_. You want some kind of _transposition_ of your data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Honestly, your starting data structure is very poorly designed. It may work on a small scale, but as you progress and your 'dictionary' of items gets larger, well you can already see it gets over whelming quickly. Try instead to make a class, and create different instances of your structure. For example:

```
class Employees():
    def __init__(self):
        self.surname = ''
        self.salary = 0
        self.car_man = []  # if in case you want to add more than one car use a list type or just use string if you plan on keeping this a single value
```

From here you can create instances, and you would be able to keep track of them much much easier. You can even add these individual instances to a dictionary itself and you can sort them.

EX:

```
 Mark = Employees()
 Mark.surname = 'Johnson'
 Mark.salary = 5
 Mark.car_man = 'Volvo'

 John = Employees()
 John.surname = "Doe"
 John.salary = 10
 John.car_man = Daewoo
```

Do these for as many of them as you want then you could add these instances to a dictionary and be able to sort them much easier.

Adding them to a dictionary is as simple as:

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict[#key] = # your instance
```

Comment: Or an `Employee` could have a list attribute `cars` that contains `Car` objects.

Comment: Yes, I am not how OP wants his data really structured, but hopefully this will direct him to what he wants.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do a thing about the initial structure. Guess I have to try your solution and compare the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary Comprehension - though I tend to shy from it - may make your code more readable if you're that kind of person.

```
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=3)

cars = {}
for person in persons:
  for tag in persons[person]['tags']:
    if tag['name'] == 'Car manufacturer':
      if tag['value'] in cars:
          cars[tag['value']][person] = persons[person]
      else:
          cars[tag['value']] = {person:persons[person]}

pp.pprint(cars)

cars = {tag['value']:{person:persons[person]} for person in persons for tag in persons[person]['tags'] if tag['name'] == 'Car manufacturer'}
pp.pprint(cars)
```

I agree with the others about the structure of your data.  Not to mention the code you supplied does not run as provided, so it's hard for us to infer precisely what you want.

I doubt anyone will come up with a much more efficient answer than yours.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most effecient as it needs to generate the dict each time, but your tags list would be better represented as a dict than as a list of dicts with "name" and "value".

```
sorted(
    d.items(),
    key=lambda x: dict(
        (kv["name"], kv["value"])
        for kv in x[1]["tags"]
    )["Car manufacturer"]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your own answer:

```
cars = {}
for name in persons:
  for tag in persons[name]['tags']:
    if tag['name'] == 'Car manufacturer':
      cars.setdefault(tag['value'],{})[name] = persons[name]
      break
```

Producing:

```
{'Daewoo': {'John': {'surname': 'Doe',
                     'tags': [{'name': 'Salary', 'value': '10'},
                              {'name': 'Car manufacturer',
                               'value': 'Daewoo'}]}},
 'Volvo': {'Mark': {'surname': 'Johnson',
                    'tags': [{'name': 'Salary', 'value': '5'},
                             {'name': 'Car manufacturer', 'value': 'Volvo'}]}}

}
```

Not very sexy, but probably decently efficient given your datastructure.